# (1st bit + 2nd bit) in decimal number

Tags: c++

I'd like to have (1st bit + 2nd bit) in decimal number.

```
unsigned char a = 52;
unsigned char b = ((((a >> 2) & 0x1)*2)+(((a >> 1) & 0x1)*1));
// expected output: 2
```

My code works, but I think this way is pretty bad.

Comment: What is wrong with Bitwise and? `a & 0x03`

Comment: Nothing's wrong with bitwise, but the code is too big. I wonder about more elegant way.

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign The shift is 2 and 1, not 1 and 0, so it should be `(a >> 1) & 3`

Comment: The 1:st bit in 52 (dec) is 0 and so is the 2:nd. Why is the expected result 2?

Comment: @TedLyngmo start counting at `0` ...

Comment: @J.Doe The 1:st bit is bit 0.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Because 10 is 2.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `00110100` ... 0th bit is 0, 1st bit is 0, 2nd bit is 1, 3rd bit is 0, ...

Comment: @J.Doe There is no 0:th bit. 1:st bit is bit 0.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes there is. :D

Comment: @CruzJean Yes, you are right.

Comment: @J.Doe You are going to have a hard time communicating with people working in this area if you speak of the 7:th bit and mean the 8:th - just saying :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Just imagine all the wonderful confusion. Amazing possibilities :)

Comment: @J.Doe It does happen already. Once every 5-10 years someone comes to work who has confused bit counting. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the confusion is in your phrasing... You say you want 1st bit + 2nd bit, which I would argue (semantically) would be bit index 0 and 1. But from your code it's clear you really want bit index 1 and 2, hence why 52 (`110100`) would yield 2.

In this case the code you provide is easily simplified by shifting the bits one to the right and grabbing the low 2 bits:

```cpp
unsigned char a = 52;
unsigned char b = (a >> 1) & 3;
```